# how to implement code for displaing images randomly in a row?

Tags: iphone, ios4

hi all how to implement code for displaying different images randomly in a row row. Each row must be have 10 images upto six rows so help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Show us what you have so far.

Comment: Which row are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'am not a pro programmer but i also implemented something similar to what you want 
You can give a integer tag to every image using
**Image-i.tag=i** , then 
use the function **int m=(arc4random()% numOfImages);**
to generate a random number and use the image with that tag. 
hope this help's.